Prove a Characterization for Localization of Stochastic Processes
In Exercise 3.4.16 in Stochastic Calculus and Applications by Cohen and Elliott, it states:

Let $C$ be a set of processes such that if $X$ is a process with $X^T, X^S \in C,$ for $S,T$ stopping times, then $X^{\max(S,T)} \in C.$ Show that a process $Y$ satisfies $Y \in C_\textit{loc},$ if and only if, for any $t > 0$ and any $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists a stopping time $T$ such that $Y^T \in C$ and $P(T > t) > 1 - \epsilon.$


Here, for a stopping time $T$ and process $X$, $X^T$ means $(X_t^T)_t := (X_{\min(t,T)})_t$


$Y \in C_\textit{loc}$ means there is an increasing sequence of stopping times $T_n$ such that
(i) $T_n \to \infty$ almost surely and (ii) each stopped process $Y^{T_n}$ is in $C.$

I want to know how to prove the only if part, that is, I want to show $Y \in C_\text{loc}$ with the above assumption. My attempt is the following:
From the assumption, I know for each integers $n$ and $k,$ there is a stopping time $T_n^k$ such that $Y^{T_n^k} \in C$ and $P(T_n^k > n) > 1 - \frac{1}{k}.$
Letting $T_n = \sup_k T_n^k,$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n = \infty$ almost surely and $T_n$ is a stopping time.
I am stuck to prove $Y^{T_n}$ is in $C$ since the assumption only states the closedness of $C$ for the maximum of finitely many stopping times. But $T_n$ is the maximum of infinitely many stopping times.
Of course, my construction of $T_n$ may not be workable. I appreciate all the discussions.

Let $S_n$ be a sequence of stopping times such that $P(S_n > n) > 1-2^{-n}$ and $Y^{S_n} \in C$ for each $n$.
Now let $T_1 = S_1$, and for $n>1$ let $T_n = S_n \vee T_{n-1} = S_1 \vee \dots \vee S_n$. Here, $X \vee Y := \max(X,Y)$.
It is clear to see by the definition of $C$ that $Y^{T_n} \in C$ for each $n$. We claim that $T_n \rightarrow \infty$ almost surely, so $Y \in C_{loc}$.
Indeed, we see that $P(T_n > n) > P(S_n > n) > 1-2^{-n}$, i.e. $P(T_n \leq n) < 2^{-n}$. Hence, by the first Borel-Cantelli lemma, we have $P(T_n \leq n \text{ infinitely often}) = 0$, i.e. $T_n > n$ eventually almost surely. This imples that $T_n \rightarrow \infty$ almost surely.

Thanks! Got it!
